# Trouble converting floating decimal into integer

Tags: matlab

I have created a user-defined function in which the inputs are j =indices, new_loc = a 51x2 matrix of cell locations, and the size of my first col of the 51x2 matrix = 51.

```
function [x,y,w,z] = check_location(j,new_loc,size)

disp(j);
a = j / size + 1; %Finds 1st element of compared array
b = mod(j,size); %Finds 1st element of comparing array

int8(a) %Must be whole integer
int8(b) %" "

fprintf('a = %g',a)

if b == 0 %1st element cannot be 0
    b = b + 1;
else
    ;
end

fprintf('b = %g',b)

x = new_loc(a,1); % [x y]
y = new_loc(a,2);
w = new_loc(b,1); % [w z]
z = new_loc(b,2);
```

I am confused as I have tested my output with a fprintf function, and fprintf('a = %g',a) is showing a decimal number, while a = j / size + 1 is evaluating an integer. Also, I am getting the error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

```
for j = 1:numel(D)
    if D(j) < 8 & D(j) ~= 0
         [x1,y1,x2,y2] = check_location(j,new_location,numel(new_location(:,1)));
%         smallest_int = check_intensity(x1,y1,x2,y2,B); 
%         [row,col] = find(B == smallest_int) %Convert smallest_int vals w/ it's location
%         new_location(row,col) = []; %Check new_location w/ smallest_int vals and delete
    end
end
```

Here is the for loop in which I am testing my function.

Comment: Barker pointed out the error in your code, but I would also suggest you don’t cast to `int8`. MATLAB’s native type is `double`, and any other type will cause difficulties (and surprising results) when doing arithmetic. Use `floor` or `fix` to convert your `a` to an integer. `b` already is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
int8(a) %Must be whole integer
int8(b) %" "
```

both return `int8` values, but they're not stored anywhere, so they're lost. You need to assign the integer value back to the original variable.

```
a = int8(a) %Must be whole integer
b = int8(b) %" "
```